# Folder `lost+found` Shows Up via SFTP

Tags: permissions, sftp, nautilus

I have a Raspberry Pi running Ubuntu Mate 16.04. Until today, I had a thumb drive with a single partition connection connected to it and the folder `lost+found` was hidden when viewing the folder on my laptop (running Ubuntu 16.04) in Nautilus just like `/lost+found` on my laptop's system is hidden in Nautilus.

Today connected a HDD and created a raid 1. The raid is mounted in `/media/raid`. The HDD has access storage space which has its own partition which is mounted in `/media/non-raid`. Both mount points are connected to newly created partitions and both exhibit the strange behavior of `lost+found` (`/media/raid/lost+found`, `/media/non-raid/lost+found`) not being shown when I navigate to their parent directory in Nautilus on the Raspberry Pi but being shown (which they shouldn't) when I connect to my Raspi from my laptop in Nautilus via SFTP and navigate there.

The tick in `View → Show Hidden Files` of course isn't set and no other hidden files are shown. I restarted both machines.

I changed the permissions on the file systems to fit my needs. `/media/non-raid` doesn't hold any data yet, so I'm posting the output of `ll` executed at that location but the rights of `/media/raid` are the same.

```
christoph@christoph-pi:/media/non-raid$ ll
total 24
drwx------ 3 christoph christoph  4096 Oct 11 16:15 ./
drwxr-xr-x 5 root      root       4096 Oct 11 17:09 ../
drwx------ 2 root      root      16384 Oct 11 16:15 lost+found/
```

`christoph`, of course, is my username. I connect via SFTP using the same account.

What causes this strange behavior of Nautilus and how can I make `lost+found` hidden, again?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Not with the `ls` command anyway.

In Unix, a file or directory is hidden when the first character of its name is ".". That's a convention, not an actual feature of the operating system. That is, applications do you a favor by not showing you files that start with ".". There is usually a way to override that feature, e.g. with the "-a" option to ls(1).

It sounds to me like Nautilus has some extra code in it to hide other things as well, such as lost+found. Some would call this a mis-feature, but I suspect it's configurable.

In addition, some operating systems such as Mac OS allow files to have extra attributes, one of which is "hidden". I think the ls(1) command might honor that flag (but I haven't tested this.) If you're using Nautilus, then you're probably not running Mac OS, so this won't apply to you.

In general, command-line tools such as ls(1), especially older ones, won't have these features. IMHO, this is a good thing. Ultimately, you want some tools out there that will always tell you the truth. `ls -a` will always tell you the truth about what's in a directory.